# ERROR: Unrecognized command: service

Tags: windows, tunnel, ngrok

We've got [ngrok.exe](https://ngrok.com/download) setup inside:

```
C:\Program Files\ngrok\ngrok.exe
```

Which we wanted to run as a service:

Hence, [as suggested](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-link#service)  we've created a `ngrok.yml` file at:

```
C:\Program Files\ngrok\ngrok.yml
```

The [content](https://ngrok.com/docs#config) of which is the following:

```
tunnels:
  tunnelOne:
    proto: http
    addr: 3000
```

The `path` variable is set to `C:\Program Files\ngrok`.

Whenever we run the following command:

```
ngrok service install -config C:\Program Files\ngrok\ngrok.yml
```

It throws the following error:

> ERROR:  Unrecognized command: service

[Posted the issue to Github too](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/436)

Comment: this feature is only available in ngrok link which is paid version of ngrok

Answer (score 1):

Read the author's [comment on this error](https://github.com/inconshreveable/ngrok/issues/236) and it seems like this functionality is related to [ngrok link](https://ngrok.com/product/ngrok-link) rather than the baseline ngrok. And, scrolling to the top of the linked site ([here](https://ngrok.com/docs/ngrok-link#service)), it says "Docs for ngrok link."